# vtiger 7 related module quick create autofill

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I've created a custom module and related it to vtiger organizations module. The custom module has an uitype10 attribute to link the record to the organization.

Everything works except that the organization name field in the quick create form of my related module is not automatically filled in. What I mean is:

- if I go to organizations list, click an organization, click on Contacts icon and then click on the add button to add a new contact from the organization panel, the quick create form shows the organizazion name already filled in with the organization name I currently am in.
- if I go to organizations list, click an organization, click on my custom module icon and then click on the add button to add a new record from the organization panel, the quick create form shows the organization name as empty. I have to manually write the organization name in it.

What I need is that my module behaves like the contacts module, so when I add a new record from the organization panel, the field for organization name should already filled in.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Vtiger store Relation between 2 modules in `vtiger_relatedlists` table and based on details in this table Create Button URL will get generated in `function getCreateViewUrl()` in RelationListView.php. You can get core file in `modules/Vtiger/models/RelationListView.php`.

**Solution :** Table `crestel_relatedlists` will have `relationfieldid` which store the fieldid of your organization module against relation with your module. If `relationfieldid` is set to "0" then you have to set it with exact fieldid which you can get from `vtiger_field` table.